# Shared Preference & Spinner Not Maintaining State

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I have a spinner like this:

```
// Spinner 1


final Spinner plan = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paymentplan);
sAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings);
sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
plan.setAdapter(sAdapter);

// plan.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);
plan.setSelection(prefsDisplay.getInt("spinnerSelection1", 0));
plan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListenerPlan());
```

When user clicks, I want it to save state:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
                Editor editor2 = prefsPlan.edit();
                int selectedPosition1 = plan.getSelectedItemPosition();
                editor2.putInt("spinnerSelection1", selectedPosition1);
                editor2.commit();


}
```

It saves the position in SharedPref, but the spinner goes back to default.  Anyone see something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are storing `spinnerSelection`

```
editor1.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);
```

an accessing `spinnerSelection1`

```
prefsDisplay.getInt("spinnerSelection1", 0)
```

make them consistent.

**Update**

when you are accessing `plan.getSelectedItemPosition()`. then spinner is visible? I guess NO.

try to put a public variable for selected position. And update `selected position` in your `MyOnItemSelectedListenerPlan`. And then store that position in shared preferences. I guess it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> to Save:

```
int selectedPosition = yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);
editor.commit();
```

> to Load:

```
 yourSpinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spinnerSelection",0));
```

if you are array used it should changed like this

```
String selectedString = yourArray[yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];
editor.putString("spinnerSelection", selectedString);
editor.commit();
```

> checking array[i] against the value stored in prefs.if you use an
>   ArrayList instead this part could be done without the loop by calling

```
ArrayList.indexOf(prefs.getString("spinnerSelection", "");
```

> when you commit show all above array item gone. show no one into
>   array.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and first save position of current selected item into one integer variable on `onItemSelectedListener()` using below code and after that store this variable value into shared preferences.

For Store value into one Variable.

```
int index;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Here Position is Item Index
    index = position;
}
```

For Store Value into shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putInt("SelectedIndex", index);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And see below link for more information

[Android Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

[Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

after saving to the preferences, you have to set the selected item to the spinner for further uses

as

```
int pos = prefsDisplay.getInt("spinnerSelection", "0");
display.setSelection(pos);
```

but you are using `spinnerSelection1`. so By default if there is no matching in the preferences. the default value will return. so Here **0** is returned and spinner is set to first position

Comment: But I am setting here:  `plan.setSelection(prefsDisplay.getInt("spinnerSelection1", 0));`

Comment: Also, I changed my code, I had wrong code.  spinnerSelection is consistent.

Comment: try to print the `spinnerSelection1` when you are setting to the spinner in the logcat